# treeview disappeared when i reopen the form

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I would like to ask for your help. I am stuck to this for more than two days, I've searched the net but unfortunately got no answer.

I have a program in vb 2008 and a database (SQL Server 2008). I have this form which contains treeview. The items display is selected from the database. When i run the program and open the form the treeview items displayed (at first), but when i closed the form and try to open it again the treeview disappear. I dont know why :( . Why is it disappearing? Can somebody help me please. Thank you.

Below is my code....

@form_load

```
Private Sub frmProfile_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call conecDB()
    Call initCMD()

    FillTable()
    CreateTree() 'create the treeview node
    findNode()   'find and checked the selected nodes that was given to the profile

End Sub
```

'the functions

```
Private Sub FillTable()
    'tv1.Nodes.Clear()
    dtable.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
    dtable.Columns.Add("NAME", GetType(String))
    dtable.Columns.Add("PARENT", GetType(Integer))
    dtable.Columns.Add("LEVEL", GetType(Integer))

    qSQL = "select mod_id,name,parent,level,sort,mnu_name from module where status='A' and parent!=-1"
    With comDB
        .CommandText = qSQL
        rdDB = .ExecuteReader
    End With

    Do While rdDB.Read
        dtable.Rows.Add(rdDB!mod_id, rdDB!name.ToString(), rdDB!parent)
        My.Application.DoEvents()
    Loop

    For i = 0 To dtable.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim ID1 As String = dtable.Rows(i).Item("ID").ToString
        dtable.Rows(i).Item("LEVEL") = FindLevel(ID1, 0)
    Next
    rdDB.Close()
End Sub

 Private Function FindLevel(ByVal ID As String, ByRef Level As Integer) As Integer
    For i = 0 To dtable.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim ID1 As String = dtable.Rows(i).Item("ID").ToString
        Dim Parent1 As String = dtable.Rows(i).Item("PARENT").ToString

        If ID = ID1 Then
            If Parent1 = 0 Then
                Return Level
            Else
                Level += 1
                FindLevel(Parent1, Level)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Level
End Function

Private Sub CreateTree()
    tv1.Nodes.Clear()
    Dim MaxLevel1 As Integer = CInt(dtable.Compute("MAX(LEVEL)", ""))
    Dim i, j As Integer

    For i = 0 To MaxLevel1
        Dim Rows1() As DataRow = dtable.Select("LEVEL = " & i)
        For j = 0 To Rows1.Count - 1
            Dim ID1 As String = Rows1(j).Item("ID").ToString
            Dim Name1 As String = Rows1(j).Item("NAME").ToString
            'Dim mName As String = Rows1(j).Item("mNAME").ToString
            Dim Parent1 As String = Rows1(j).Item("PARENT").ToString

            If Parent1 = 0 Then
                tv1.Nodes.Add(ID1, Name1)
            Else
                Dim TreeNodes1() As TreeNode = tv1.Nodes.Find(Parent1, True)

                If TreeNodes1.Length > 0 Then
                    TreeNodes1(0).Nodes.Add(ID1, Name1)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub findNode()
    Dim rName As String = String.Empty
    Dim b As Boolean = True

    qSQL = "select access_id,mnu_name from profile_details where prof_id=" & lblPID.Text & ""
    With comDB
        .CommandText = qSQL
        rdDB = .ExecuteReader
    End With
    Do While rdDB.Read
        rName = rdDB!access_id.ToString()
        Try
            Dim arr As TreeNode() = tv1.Nodes.Find(rName, b)
            For i = 0 To arr.Length - 1
                tv1.SelectedNode = arr(i)
                tv1.SelectedNode.Checked = True
            Next
        Catch
            MsgBox(Err)
        End Try
    Loop
    rdDB.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying the TreeView control disappears, or that it has no contents/nodes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4934010/17034

Comment: @Mort... it really disappear. at first open, it shows, when i close the form and reopen it, cant see the treeview.